# What do I lose by disable uPNP in a printer

Tags: networking, printer, windows-8.1, upnp

On my large home network I have a network printer which works well with both Windows Vista, Windows 7, Mac OS and Ubuntu Linux. Recently I added a Windows 8.1 computer to my network, and that caused the software in the printer to crash every 10-30 minutes - even when nobody was printing anything.

I discovered that I could eliminate the problem by disabling uPNP in the printer. This leads me to two questions:

1) What does Windows 8.1 do with uPNP that Windows 7 doesn't do and which might cause the software in my printer to crash?

2) What am I losing by disabling uPNP in the printer? (All the computers can still see and use the printer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I am aware, nothing in particular. *My guess* is that this will be hard to answer without further debugging.
2. If your printer uses UPnP, it is likely that it has some sort of feature where you can connect **to** your printer **from outside your network**. Basically, it sets up port forwarding by communicating with your router via a standard for this sort of negotiation between networked devices.

   Provided you only use your printer on your local network, I see no reason this should negatively impact you in any way. In fact, some might claim having UPnP disabled would be for the better, as your printer would **not** be reachable from WAN.